# OpenCL ATI Mobility Radeon 4500 and Intel Core(TM)2 Duo CPU

Tags: opencl

My laptop has ATI Radeon 4500 graphics card and Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8700 2.53GHz as CPU. When I query OpenCL for platforms the Output is like this:

```
    Found 2 Platforms
==================Platform No 0======================
CL_PLATFORM_NAME   : AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
CL_PLATFORM_VERSION: OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (937.2)
CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE: FULL_PROFILE
CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS: cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices
======================================================

==================Platform No 1======================
CL_PLATFORM_NAME   : Intel(R) OpenCL
CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR : Intel(R) Corporation
CL_PLATFORM_VERSION: OpenCL 1.2 LINUX
CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE: FULL_PROFILE
CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS: cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_spir cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_fp64 
======================================================
```

and when I query for opencl devices the output is like this

```
Number of OpenCL platforms available in the system: 2
Printing OpenCL Device Info For Platform ID : 0
==================Device No 0======================
CL_DEVICE_NAME: ATI RV710
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
CL_DRIVER_VERSION: CAL 1.4.1734
CL_DEVICE_VERSION: OpenCL 1.0 AMD-APP (937.2)
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS: 2
====================================================

==================Device No 1======================
CL_DEVICE_NAME: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8700  @ 2.53GHz
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR: GenuineIntel
CL_DRIVER_VERSION: 2.0 (sse2)
CL_DEVICE_VERSION: OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (937.2)
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS: 2
====================================================


Printing OpenCL Device Info For Platform ID : 1
==================Device No 0======================
CL_DEVICE_NAME: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8700  @ 2.53GHz
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR: Intel(R) Corporation
CL_DRIVER_VERSION: 1.2.0.92
CL_DEVICE_VERSION: OpenCL 1.2 (Build 92)
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS: 2
====================================================
```

I think something is wrong. Because in the Platform ID 0 which belongs to graphics card there is two devices. One for AMD(ATI) and another for Intel. But in Platform ID 1 which belongs to Intel CPU there is only one device.
I have installed both AMD APP and Intel OpenCL library.
I can see this output in AMD Codex software and I'm sure about the output of the code.
Why does ATI(AMD) Graphics card show two devices while I have two core in the CPU.
I'm so confused.
please help.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMD OpenCL implementation supports CPUs as well as AMD GPUs. However, the Intel OpenCL implementation supports CPUs as well was Intel GPUs (at least on windows systems) but it does **not** support AMD GPUs. So your output is perfectly fine and nothing is wrong.

Comment: Based on [this](http://bazinevis.com/openclICD.png) picture from "OpenCL Programming By Example" book every device in a platform should categorized under that platform. But in the my computer intel cpu devices also included in ATI(AMD) platform. How can it happen?

Comment: Read this answer again carefully. The first sentence states that AMD's OpenCL can target any CPU, not only AMD CPUs.

Comment: Both the AMD platform and the Intel platform expose the CPU device. It's the same CPU. In my experience, Intel's CPU driver produces faster code than AMD's.